# Apache Airflow | How to check response coming from a command while using SSHOperator?

Tags: ssh, airflow

How to check response coming from a command while using SSHOperator?

```
t1  = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='conn_box2',
                 task_id='t1',
                 command='Rscript /code/demo.R',
                 do_xcom_push=True,
                 response_check=lambda response: True if "status:200" in response.text else False,
                 dag=dag
)
```

My R scripts returns status:200 if the execution goes well. And I want to track it. My task t1 should only complete if status is 200. 
If R script returns status:300 its a failed one. But since the execution is completed without any error in UI task turns into green(which i don't want)

I code above is able to capture the response in xcom, but how do i validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```py
bash_command = """
set -e;
Rscript /code/demo.R  | grep 'status:200'  &> /dev/null 
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo "Task Successful"
else
   echo "Task Failed"
   exit 1
fi
"""


t1  = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='conn_box2',
                 task_id='t1',
                 command=bash_command,
                 dag=dag)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following `bash_command`:

```sh
if Rscript /code/demo.R | grep -q 'status:200'; then
  echo "Task Successful"
else
  echo "Task Failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

The `SSHOperator` does not have `response_check` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is unable to interpret exit command

[2021-09-07 06:36:58,164] {ssh.py:142} INFO - ps_count is 23, There might be some processes are running
[2021-09-07 06:36:58,169] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - SSH operator error: error running cmd:

## code:

set -e;
ps_count=`jpsexec | grep -v execute | wc -l`
if [ $ps_count -ne 0 ]
then
echo "ps_count is $ps_count, There might be some processes are running"
exit 1
else
echo "All processed were stopped..!"
fi

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.